# Elastic apm over nodejs is not sending error messages

Tags: elasticsearch, apm

I have the following simple code below to run APM with logs.
APM is firing stats and looks like it works great.
But the problems that the errors are not appearing anywhere in Kibana
What am I missing?

```
  const agent = ElasticApm.start({
    serviceName: 'onprem',
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8200',
    environment: config.getNestEnv()
  });
  const error = new Error("test");
  agent.logger.error(error, 'test');
  agent.logger.error( 'test');
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution in the mean time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need check source for showing log message, and choose right indices

In Kibana Dashboard > Observability > Log > Settings ( top-right corner ) and select, fill Log sources

If it still not show, just try use

```
agent.captureError(new Error("test"))
```